# How to generate and send certificate in ios to Web service through NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, web-services, iis-7, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a Web Service, i hosted in IIS7 and generated a self signed certificate for it.

And also i have iPad application as front-end. When i try to connect them using NSURLConnection it is working with this code.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"IP/HostName"])
        {

            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

!!! The problem is when i check over **"SSL Required"** on the IIS , i am getting an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

How can i generate and send certificate from client (application) side.

Dose anybody have an idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, Pls give any solution to this....